# Assign standard exit status to a makefile variable

Tags: makefile, make

I'm trying to save the standard exit status of a command in a variable of my makefile, but I don't know how to do it.

I've tried this:

```
pruebas:
    @A= $(ls)
```

...but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You can execute a command in the shell from the Makefile by using the `$(shell command)` syntax.
If for instance you would want to exit status of the `ls` command in bash you would type:

```
ls --qwfpgjl > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?
```

This might need some explanation: the `> /dev/null 2>&1` part redirects both standard output and standard error to /dev/null so you don't see any output, and then 'echo $?' prints the exit status of the last command. You can try this in the command line to see if it works for you, for instance

```
ls --qwfpgjl > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?
```

should give you

```
2
```

since that is the error `ls` returns when there is an unknown argument (see the [`ls` man page](https://man.cx/ls)).

Now how to include this in your Makefile? Simply add the line

```
A=$(shell ls > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $$?)
```

to your Makefile. Note the extra `$` in `$$?`, it tells `make` that `$?` is not a variable in the Makefile.

That should be it! Here you can see the Makefile I used to test this behavior:

```
#SHELL := /bin/bash
A=$(shell ls > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $$? )

test:
    @echo $A
.PHONY: test
```

---

**Notes:**
`make` picks the `/bin/sh` shell by default, but you can override this by setting

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

This can be useful for more complicated commands that don't execute in `/bin/sh`.